# Slidedown animation broken

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a problem with my Slidedown effect, because his animation is quite broke when i try to open the menu. This is the animation broken that it gives: https://gyazo.com/450138f37f6b8e99c1e9fc452a3108e4 As you can see, the rows appear on the left and then they move quickly to the right, and that isn't what i want. I need it to work normally like a common slidedown

Here is my code, i hope that someone will be able to help me!

```
$("#crystal").click(function(){
  $("#crystal1").slideDown(300);
  $("#eventi1").slideUp(300);
  $("#stanze1").slideUp(100);
});

$("#stanze").click(function(){
  $("#crystal1").slideUp(100);
  $("#eventi1").slideUp(300);
  $("#stanze1").slideDown(300);
});

$("#eventi").click(function(){
  $("#crystal1").slideUp(100);
  $("#stanze1").slideUp(100);
  $("#eventi1").slideDown(300);
});

.promo2{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #133c54;
  border: 3px solid #095a87;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 520px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 520px;
  font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
}

.crystals{
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #133c54;
  border: 3px solid #095a87;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: 320px;
  max-width: 520px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 520px;
  font-family: Ubuntu Condensed;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0px;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="promo2" id="crystal">
  <div style="height:auto; width:96px; height:96px; background-image:url(image/crystal2.png); float:left;"></div>
  <div style="font-size: 41px;">
    Ricarica Crystal + <span style="color:#f7cc02;">Promotion Point</span>
    <img style="position: relative;left: 55px;top: -28px;" src="image/frecciadown.png">
  </div>

  <div style="display:none" id="crystal1">
    <div class="crystals" id="first" style="z-index:12; top:14px;">
      <span style="color:#47c5ff;"> 50 Crystal</span> + <span  style="color:#f7cc02;">2 Promotion Points</span>
      <img src="image/frecciaright.png" style="left: 140px; position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div class="crystals" style="z-index:11; top:-7px;">
      <span style="color:#47c5ff;"> 150 Crystal</span> + <span  style="color:#f7cc02;">5 Promotion Points</span>
      <img src="image/frecciaright.png" style="left: 136px;position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div class="crystals" style="z-index:10; top:-27px;">
      <span style="color:#47c5ff;"> 400 Crystal</span> + <span  style="color:#f7cc02;">10 Promotion Points</span>
      <img src="image/frecciaright.png" style="left: 132px;position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div class="crystals" style="z-index:9; top:-47px;">
      <span style="color:#47c5ff;"> 850 Crystal</span> + <span  style="color:#f7cc02;">14 Promotion Points</span>
      <img src="image/frecciaright.png" style="left: 132px;position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div class="crystals" style="z-index:8; top:-67px">
      <span style="color:#47c5ff;"> 1800 Crystal</span> + <span  style="color:#f7cc02;">20 Promotion Points</span>
      <img src="image/frecciaright.png" style="left: 128px;position: relative;">
    </div>
    <div class="crystals" style="z-index:7; top:-90px">
      <span style="color:#47c5ff;"> 4000 Crystal</span> + <span  style="color:#f7cc02;">30 Promotion Points</span>
      <img src="image/frecciaright.png" style="left: 128px;position: relative;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: There must be more to the code than this, as it seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6sjg3n5/.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I managed to fix your slidedown issue with the following changes:

1. Turned the div beginning with 'Ricarica' into a paragraph
2. Changed the `crystal1` id and its contents to use an unordered list instead of a div structure
3. Changed border properties of the `.crystals` class to enhance item structure
4. Other minor edits

In the long run, parts of your HTML and CSS needed to be rewritten in order to have a working, smooth slidedown.

Fixed code is at http://jsfiddle.net/jkantner/grkmwyav/.